# Do not use display gstreamer aarch 64 linux

Tags: video, gstreamer, video-processing, wayland, google-coral

I am using gstreamer on google coral dev board and performing video analytics on it.
The platform details are :

Linux bored-horse 4.9.51-imx #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 14 20:34:37 UTC 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux

I have a pipeline of the form :

```
GST_DEBUG=*gl*:5 gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc  ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream  ! glupload ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! glfilterbin filter=glcolorscale  ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=320,height=180 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=320,height=180 ! appsink name=appsink sync=false emit-signals=true max-buffers=1 drop=true
```

It works fine when run from a terminal. However when i execute the pipeline as a background [service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) , it fails because background service do not have access to display. Anyways I dont want to display the window , i just want to connect the data to the appsink , so that i can perform video analytics on it.

So anyone has any idea about , how to force it to not use display  and just forward the data to appsink . Please help

Comment: Not the answer to question, but an idea for debugging.  You can use screen for debugging your code. Run `screen -dmS your_script.sh` at startup. Then you can use `screen -ls` to list screen apps, and 'screen -r <id>' to recover your screen.

Comment: OpenGL is normally instantiated on a running X session in the driver. So it is "normal" that it requires a running X session. You may want to do some research on "OpenGL headless" to come up with alternative ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have contact us for the same query and I've responded, but here is the service file so other can reference:

```
[Unit]
Description=Back service
After=weston.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/mendel/service_script.sh
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem, I believe was that you needed to set the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` env variable.

This is working for me:

```
mendel@bored-quill:~$ sudo systemctl status back
● back.service - Back service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/back.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-05 14:48:57 UTC; 6h ago
 Main PID: 13522 (service_script.)
    Tasks: 10 (limit: 797)
   Memory: 19.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/back.service
           ├─13522 /bin/bash /home/mendel/service_script.sh
           └─13523 gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! glupload ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! glfilterbin f

Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.284750061 13523 0xaaaad4400a30 DEBUG             gleglimage gsteglimage.c:431:_drm_direct_fourcc_from_info: Getting DRM fourcc for RGBA
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.284849062 13523 0xaaaad4400a30 DEBUG             gleglimage gsteglimage.c:661:gst_egl_image_from_dmabuf_singleplaner: fourcc AB24 (875708993) n_plane
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.285265825 13523 0xffff900040f0 DEBUG           glbasememory gstglbasememory.c:178:gst_gl_base_memory_init: new GL buffer memory:0xffff8035dcc0 size:1
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.285372385 13523 0xffff900040f0 DEBUG          glbasetexture gstglmemory.c:340:gst_gl_memory_init: new GL texture context:<glcontextegl0> memory:0xfff
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.285269905 13523 0xaaaad442b630 DEBUG      gldownloadelement gstgldownloadelement.c:419:gst_gl_download_element_prepare_output_buffer:<gldownloadeleme
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.286813716 13523 0xffff900040f0 DEBUG                gldebug gstgldebug.c:320:_gst_gl_debug_callback:<glcontextegl0> low: GL debug marker from third p
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.286898196 13523 0xffff900040f0 DEBUG               glfilter gstglfilter.c:981:gst_gl_filter_filter_texture: calling filter_texture with textures in:2
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.287709642 13523 0xaaaad4400a30 DEBUG             gleglimage gsteglimage.c:431:_drm_direct_fourcc_from_info: Getting DRM fourcc for RGBA
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.287806243 13523 0xaaaad4400a30 DEBUG             gleglimage gsteglimage.c:661:gst_egl_image_from_dmabuf_singleplaner: fourcc AB24 (875708993) n_plane
Mar 05 21:43:02 bored-quill service_script.sh[13522]: 6:54:05.288226006 13523 0xffff900040f0 DEBUG           glbasememory gstglbasememory.c:178:gst_gl_base_memory_init: new GL buffer memory:0xffff8035dcc0 size:1
```

Comment: Thanks i was experimenting with  GST_GL_WINDOW=gbm in  the pipeline. Now its been has working for me too.